# Can't import shapes from Word to PowerPoint 2013; works in Office 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy-paste, powerpoint

I'm writing a PowerPoint macro that opens a Word document and imports every picture in the document to its own slide. Because I can't place the Word InlineShape objects directly in PowerPoint, apparently, I'm using the clipboard. The relevant code is:

```
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim SourceDoc As Document
Dim TargetSlide As Slide
Dim Figures As Word.InlineShapes
Dim Figure As Word.InlineShape
Dim TargetShapeRange As ShapeRange

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set SourceDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=PathToFile, ReadOnly:=True)
Set Figures = SourceDoc.InlineShapes

For Each Figure In Figures
    Figure.Range.Select
    Figure.Application.Selection.Copy
    Set TargetSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, _
      ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(6))
    Set TargetShapeRange = TargetSlide.Shapes.Paste
Next Figure
```

With PowerPoint 2010 and Word 2010, this works perfectly. In PowerPoint 2013 (with Word 2013 installed, and referencing the Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library rather than 14.0), the `Set TargetShapeRange = TargetSlide.Shapes.Paste` line gives me run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)':

> Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here.

I've tried using the `Copy` and `CopyAsPicture` methods on both the `Selection` and `Range` objects. I've tried using the `Shapes.PasteSpecial` command. I've tried several different ways of accessing the Word Application object. Nothing works.

Notably, if I modify the code to copy the preceding paragraph of text in addition to the picture, the script works—it retrieves the text, but not the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is almost two years old but I found this through google after having a similar issue so I'll post this here.

Try

```
Figure.Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True
```

right before copying. It works for me even with screenupdating disabled or if the application is not visible.